# INSERT INTO with Rand() function throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have a table, `Benefit`, where the policy number is to be generated randomly and should be unique of course. Below are my statements and query.

```
INSERT INTO Benefit([Company Name], [Policy #]) 
VALUES ('Assumption Life', RAND(100) * 100)

INSERT INTO Benefit([Company Name], [Policy #]) 
VALUES ('Aviva Canada', RAND(1) * 12)

INSERT INTO Benefit([Company Name], [Policy #]) 
VALUES ('Blue Cross' RAND(100) * 100)

INSERT INTO Benefit([Company Name], [Policy #]) 
VALUES ('Health & Dental Insurance' RAND(100) * 100)
```

I get the response:

```
Started executing query at Line 123
(1 row affected)
(1 row affected)
```

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Benefit__2E118E21CDDEB4E7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Benefit'. The duplicate key value is (71).
>
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Benefit__2E118E21CDDEB4E7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Benefit'. The duplicate key value is (71).

The first two are successfully executed as the `RAND()` functions are a bit different, but from 3rd it throws a duplication exception, since it is same as 1st record.

I tried `RAND()`, and it always assigns 0. And from second row, throws same error.

Why it doesn't generate random number? Am I not clear with how to use `RAND()` function?

Comment: Please consult the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), *For a specified seed value, the result returned is always the same.* i.e. you can only use it once else you reset the sequence.

Comment: please show your table schema definition

Comment: also from the doc `Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.`

Comment: As @DaleK stated, the returned `RAND` value will always be the same. I would suggest maybe using a `SEQUENCE` to get your value - this can be better controled yo give unique values, or just add a `DEFAULT` constraint to the column as an `IDENTITY`

Comment: @MartinCairney I have PK to be generated as IDENTITY so cannot use it again in the same table. But can you please elaborate a bit or provide some reference on SEQENCE?

Comment: refer to the doc on sequence

Comment: @Kopal refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for `SEQUENCE`

Comment: @DaleK yes I checked many questions on this RAND() function but none helped. Although the solution I accepted did.

Comment: @Kopal the suggested duplicate exactly answers your question *Why it doesn't generate a random number*. But maybe your question was actually how to generate a unique random sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This explains the usage of RAND](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/rand.php)

The statement of interest is "**The RAND function will return a repeatable sequence of random numbers each time a particular seed value is used.**"

To create a random decimal number between two values (range), you can use the following formula:

```
SELECT RAND()*(b-a)+a;
```